# Getting child view reaches to top in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I am working on Android App, My requirement is a child of RelativeLayout which is child of ScrollView, How I get when child of RelativeLayout reaches to top while scrolling?

My Code OnScrollChnnged is

```
final LinearLayout shareAndFuirteLayOut = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.shareAndFuirteLayOut);
    final ScrollView mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.mainScrollView);

    final ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener onScrollChangedListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {


        }
    };

    mainScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private ViewTreeObserver observer;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (observer == null) {
                observer = mainScrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
                observer.addOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener);
            } else if (!observer.isAlive()) {
                observer.removeOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener);
                observer = mainScrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
                observer.addOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post the code you tried

Comment: You should be able to make it using a combination of ScrollView.getScrollY() & RelativeLayout.GetY()

Answer (score 0):

Detailing @Nanoc comment, the code will go as

```
            if (nestedScrollView.getScrollY() > View.getY()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "View visible");
                stickyHeaderLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                stickyHeaderLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```